# My token is not converting to BNB on transfer with testnet

Tags: testnets, transfer

I have copied 1Love's code; https://1love.charity/: https://bscscan.com/address/0x25096f414c11a41c802a01bfa4210d76c88da838

However, on transfers I do not recieve bnb in my charity or marketing wallet.

My router is: router = IDEXRouter(0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1);

I have changed the; marketingFeeReciever to my marketingwallet, and the same with charityFeeReciever.

Can anybody see what the problem is?

Comment: It is working for example in this [transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x8e4a5c46b2eb512e9fd05b8660418bf117e40ee2b08d81b409e3f0b0038c745b) the charityFee did receive some BNB.

Comment: Yes, but this is not at the testnet

Comment: Sorry, I thought you linked to your contract, not the original. The contract has a function `shouldSwapBack()`  that checks several parameters before forwarding funds. I'd guess some parameters make the condition false so it is skipped.